# how does indirect addressing work in assembly language motorola 68k

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I have this code:

```
loop2
        move.b  (a4)+,d3      * moving the morse code array input to d3
        muls    #5,d3
        add.b   $d3(a6),d3    * moving the character in morse code array to d4
        move.b  d3,d4
        cmp.b   #dot,d4
```

Here, I am accessing an array starting at `a4`. I am taking an element of the array and multiplying it with 5 to move to the memory location where I have the desired element.

`a6` represents the starting point of an array which contains certain character.

the statement `$d3(a6),d3` wokrs but the code gets faulty
as i know the code d3(a6),d3 should be correct but it show me an error. how should i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is since `$` is for specifying hex constants, and `d3` is technically a valid hex constant, it's using `a6 + 0xd3` as the memory address. What you're trying to accomplish uses different syntax, namely *both* registers are in the parentheses: `(a6,d3)`

So the correct statement is:

```
add.b   (a6,d3),d3
```

Comment: sorry but i just edited the question as earlier it conveyed something else.

Comment: the address of a6 is 10CC 
and d3 is 32 (decimal value 2)
so muls #5,d5 should be FA 
and 10CC + FA should 11C6 and i need the content of 11C6 in d4 but that's not what i am getting in d4

Comment: `add.b` is adding the contents of the address to register `d3`, is that what you want? If not, you should use `move.b` instead.

Comment: let us say a6 is 1000 and d3 is 10 then i want to move to the 1010th position just like accessing the 10th position of an array like array[10]. then i need to copy the content at that position to d4. so in a way i am trying to access the random elements of the array and store them in d4.

Answer (score 0):

In `add.b (a6,d3),d3` you probably should declare size of d3 used for address generation: either `(a6,d3.w)` or `(a6,d3.l)`, depending on what you need. In general case, after a multiplication you have full 32bit result and should use `d3.l`. Only if you are sure that the result of multiplication fits 16bit you can use `d3.w`.

If you write code specifically for 68020+ (020,030,040,060), also consider using scaled addressing mode like `(a6,d3.w*n)`, where n is one of 1, 2, 4, 8.